# how to check null value after firstordefault?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var data = (from x in simpMeds.Descendants("PharmacyReviewer")
    select x.Element("DisplayName").Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What you want to try?

Comment: `if(data == null)` usually... Though my spidey senses tells me you have other issues

Comment: Why do `.Value.ToString()` when `.Value` is the `string` value already?

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = (from x in simpMeds.Descendants("PharmacyReviewer")
    select x.Element("DisplayName").Value.ToString()).FirstOrDefault()
```

Must check null to get property of data. i.e:

```
var property = data?.Property1; // property == null if data == null
```

Must check null to choose the other object. i.e:

```
var myValue = data ?? otherData; // myValue == otherData if data == null
```

or simply

```
if(data == null)
  //do something
else
 //do other thing
```